# How to copy a directory structure and rename a subdirectory in the destination

Tags: shell, files, cp

Given this directory structure

```bash
$ lsd --tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
.
└── / defs
    ├── / bar
    │   └── / v1
    │       └── bar.txt
    └── / foo
        └── / v1
            └── foo.txt
```

I would like to us one simple command/script to create this structure. The real structure has many more directories.

```bash
$ lsd --tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
.
└── / defs
    ├── / bar
    │   ├── / v1
    │   │   └── bar.txt
    │   └── / v2
    │       └── bar.txt
    └── / foo
        ├── / v1
        │   └── foo.txt
        └── / v2
            └── foo.txt
```

Copying and renaming the destination.

Comment: Why does it need to be one command? Could that command be a script?

Comment: What it looks like you are trying to do is to copy two different source directories into two different target directories which isn't possible with `cp`. That will require two and the closest that you can get is something like `cp -rv /path/to/v2_with_bar_file/v2 /defs/bar && cp -rv /path/to/v2_with_foo_file/v2 /defs/foo`.

Comment: Yes updated the question, clarified that it doesn't need to be "one copy command" like `cp`.

Comment: So everywhere there is a v1 directory you want a v2 created alongside that contains... what, the same file(s) as in the v1 directory?

Comment: Yes, new directories with same files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is file 'script'.

set -e   # (optional)
         #  immediately exit on some errors, like
         #  mkdir <existing directory>  

ROOT=.  # or some other directory

 # find <directories where to start>  <predicates>
 #    -type d   ... directories
 #    -name 'v1' .... exactly matching v1 
 #    -name '*v1' .... end with v1 
find "$ROOT" -type d -name 'v1'  | while read x;
     do 
       b="${x%v1}"    # remove v1 at the and
       y="${b}v2"     # add v2
       mkdir "$y"
       cp -vr "$x"/. "$y"/
     done
```

The following creates some files and directories a tests the script.
(It starts by completely removing `x`.)

```
$ rm -fr x; \
 mkdir x x/a x/a/v1 x/a/v1/d x/b x/b/v1; touch x/notcopied x/a/notcopied x/a/v1/f1 x/b/v1/f2 x/a/v1/d/f3; find x; echo -------------;\
 (cd x; bash  ../script);\
 find x;
x
x/a
x/a/notcopied
x/a/v1
x/a/v1/d
x/a/v1/d/f3
x/a/v1/f1
x/notcopied
x/b
x/b/v1
x/b/v1/f2
-------------
'./a/v1/./d' -> './a/v2/./d'
'./a/v1/./d/f3' -> './a/v2/./d/f3'
'./a/v1/./f1' -> './a/v2/./f1'
'./b/v1/./f2' -> './b/v2/./f2'
x
x/a
x/a/v2
x/a/v2/d
x/a/v2/d/f3
x/a/v2/f1
x/a/notcopied
x/a/v1
x/a/v1/d
x/a/v1/d/f3
x/a/v1/f1
x/notcopied
x/b
x/b/v2
x/b/v2/f2
x/b/v1
x/b/v1/f2
```

Note that `/.` on the line with `cp` is quite important. Without that, there will be `v2/v1` and the files inside.

Comment: I slightly updated the script to be able to pass the search and replace string, e.g.  `./create_new_version.sh v1 v2`